# printing nullptr with std::cout and printf

Tags: c++

I wonder about "cout" nullptr doesn't work.
It work only once.
But "printf" work on the main function.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  const char *np=nullptr;

  std::cout << "np: "<<np<<std::endl;
  std::cout << "np: "<<np<<std::endl;
  std::cout << "np: "<<np<<std::endl;
  printf("printf np:%s\n",np);
  std::cout << "np: "<<np<<std::endl;
  std::cout << "np: "<<np<<std::endl;
}
```

It work like below.

np: printf np:(null)

Comment: @TonyTannous Probably not. Op is not trying to print the `nullptr` keyword, but a `const char*` that _is_ null.

Comment: It is not about printing a nullptr, it is printing what the pointer is pointing on. If pointer is invalid, we have UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's undefined behaviour**

In both cases you are printing a C-style-string (a `const char *`). So the implementation needs to find the length of this string and searches the terminating null character in it. But the pointer is invalid, so you get undefined behaviour.

Technically *both* cases are UB, but the implementation of `printf` you are using seems to be recognizing the invalid pointer and prints `(null)` instead, whereas `std::cout` just crashes.

(Or maybe it also recognizes the invalid pointer and gracefully sets the fail bit, thus ignoring further operations. But ultimately it's UB, so anything can happen here.)

Comment: Thank you so much!! It really helps to me

Answer (score 0):

`nullptr` is a type of `std::nullptr_t`, which doesn't defines the any operators for `std::cout` to be able print objects of that type.

One possible way to print, it'll print zero although:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    const char *np = nullptr;

    std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(np) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Just cast it to a `const void` pointer. Then you'll get something like:

```
0
```

But not `(null)`, this is what was explained in the top.

Comment: I see!! Thanks Rohan!